# Selecting a date 13/08/2014 on web page "http://www.makemytrip.com" from Calender icon

Tags: calendar, selenium-webdriver

WebPage : http://www.makemytrip.com

I have tried using X-path but I am getting No Such Element Exception. Here is the code below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/div/a/span")).click();


    /*DatePicker is a table.So navigate to each cell   
       * If a particular cell matches value 13 then select it  
       */  
      WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]"));  
      List<WebElement> rows=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));  
      List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

      System.out.println("Rows count :" + rows.size());
      System.out.println("Column count :" + columns.size());

      for (WebElement cell: columns)
      {  
          //Select 13th Date   
          if (cell.getText().equals("13"))
          {  
              cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();  
              break;  
          }  
      }
```

Comment: Plz... let me know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with updated makemetrip website:

```
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='js-filterOptins']"));  

dateWidget= dateWidget.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dateFilter hasDatepicker']/div/div"));


List<WebElement> columns=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

System.out.println("Column count :" + columns.size());

for (WebElement cell: columns)
{  
     //Select 16th Date   
     if (cell.getText().equals("16"))
     {  
         cell.findElement(By.linkText("16")).click(); 
         System.out.println(cell);
         break;  
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[2]/div/a/span")).click();


/*DatePicker is a table.So navigate to each cell   
   * If a particular cell matches value 13 then select it  
   */  
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.id(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]"));
```

to this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@tabindex='35']")).click();
WebElement dateWidget = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ui-datepicker-div']/div[1]"));
```

Here you have used `id` instead of `xpath`. Please change it.

Comment: Can you please let me know why you changed the xpath ? I want to understand how to decide what to select as xpath.

Comment: you need to check for the visible element in DOM. This xpath which you used is not able to find the required element. Hope this solution worked for you.